# Statistics: making scores a number between 0 and 1

Tags: statistics, programming

Silly question, but I do not know how to do it:

I let a computer play 100.000 games. I want to do some statistics on that. I would like to see how good the computer performed.

**Question**
What is the correct action to take from here?

My thoughts: taking the draws, the wins and losses. On the x-axis I put the number of games. On the y-axis I put the wins/draws/losses. Does that ok or silly?

I figured it might be smart to make them y-axis between 0 and 1. Is there a formula for that? Something I could use with R?

Comment: I mean it probably depends on what you're trying to do but the bog-standard way to do this is probably "points per game," where a win is 1 point, a loss is 0 points, and a draw is a 1/2-point. Kinda just based on chess scoring.

Comment: There is no wrong or right here, but I think a Pie or Box Diagram might be better to visualize the data.

Comment: Also, allowing negative values for $y$ might be useful to normalize it: W$=1$, L$=-1$, D$=0$